# помогите , нужно получить поле из базы данных в python

Tags: python, sql, telegram-bot, sqlite, sqlite3

Я пользуюсь telebot api и sqlite3, и мне нужно, чтобы пользователь мог нажать кнопку, и ему выводилось сообщение о количестве денег на его аккаунте из базы данных.

В базе данных есть столбик `user_id` и `moneys`, кнопка готова, а вот как извлечь поле `moneys`, зная `user_id`, я не знаю, так как только начал изучение sql.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `select moneys from таблица where user_id=значение;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# id пользователя
user_id = 1

# подключение к бд
with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # получаем значение moneys по id пользователя
    cursor.execute("SELECT moneys FROM table WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)) 
    # сохраняем значение monyes
    user_moneys = cursor.fetchone()

print(user_moneys)
```